# thymeleaf - sum of objects in list inside a list

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I use spring boot + thymeleaf and mySQL DB
I have 3 entities:

- Category
- SubCategory
- Porducts

[The current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBzsm.png)

I would like to show the sum of products in the table

This is the code to show the sum of sub category:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="category : ${categories}">
      <td th:text="${category.name}" />
      <td th:text="${#lists.size(category.subCategories)}" />
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) and aggregate functions to accomplish this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:each="category : ${categories}">
    <td th:text="${category.name}" />
    <td th:text="${#lists.size(category.subCategories)}" />
    <td th:text="${#aggregates.sum(category.subCategories.![#lists.size(products)])}" />
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The expressions `category.subCategories.![#lists.size(products)]` produces a list of the products in subCategories, which you can just sum using `#aggregates.sum`.